# Making a div visible when another div's margin is equal to 0px

Tags: jquery, html

Basically I have a div that moves horizontally when a right or left arrow is clicked. using the following jQuery:

```
$(".arrow_right").click(function(){
$(".movingdiv").animate({marginLeft: '+=-225px'}, 500);
});

$(".arrowcontainer_left").click(function(){
$(".movingdiv").animate({marginLeft: '+=225px'}, 500);
});
```

To ensure the moving div does not go off the screen, I would like the left arrow's css to change to:

```
  visibility:hidden;
```

when the moving div's margin-left is equal to 0px. And the same for the right arrow when the moving div's margin-left is equal to 675px (or three clicks)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this: http://techfoobar.com/jquery-style-listener/ - Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Comment: check margin-left in call back function.

Comment: I think by mistake you have made mistake in margin-left +/-. You should do margin-left + where you have done -.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
$(".arrowcontainer_left").click(function(){
    $(".movingdiv").animate({marginLeft: '+=225px'}, 500,function() { 
        if($(".movingdiv").css("margin-left") == "675px")
        {   // your stuff to hide
        }
    });
});
```